# Assigning column value in Trigger causes "Unknown system variable" error

Tags: mysql, triggers

All the examples I've found seem the same as my code, yet I am having a hard time getting it to work. Here's the table,

```
CREATE TABLE `samfoo` (
`test` varchar(10) default NULL,
`trig_field` varchar(10) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And here's the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS footrigger$$

CREATE TRIGGER samtrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON samfoo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET trig_field = 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this, I get the error `Unknown system variable 'trig_field'`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `SET NEW.trig_field := 1;`

Comment: THANK YOU. For some reason I could not find an example or tutorial, and the documentation (as usual) was way too verbose. What does the := operator mean?

Comment: My actual code is `SET NEW.date_string := date(time_stamp);`, and I'm getting an error: `unknown column 'time_stamp' in 'field list'. Any ideas?

Comment: what is `time_stamp`? If it's a field in the same table, you need to access it  like `NEW.time_stamp` or `OLD.time_stamp` (in your case since it's `before insert` trigger `OLD.` doesn't make sense, it should be `NEW.time_stamp`).

Comment: Wonderful! So what exactly do `NEW` and `OLD` refer to? And what should I read to really understand this stuff? I hate hacking it together like this. You've been extremely helpful, by the way.

Comment: `new` and `old` are pseudo-rows that are available inside row-level triggers and allow accessing new and old values of the modified record respectively. `new` makes no sense in `delete` triggers, `old` - in `insert` triggers. To summarize, in insert triggers you can access only `new`, in update - `new` and `old`, in `delete` - only `old`.